# characterization of sets stable by a central symmetry

Tags: geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I was looking for a characterization of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are stable under a central symmetry.

Let $s_M$ denote the symmetry of center $M$.

If $A$ is such a set that is measurable with $\mu(A)=1$, then there is a center $M$ such that $A=s_M(A)$, hence $\mu(A \cap s_M(A))=1$.

Now, if a set is not stable under a central symmetry, is it true that for any point $M$, one has $\mu(A \cap s_M(A))<1$? By a compactness argument, this would imply the existence of a constant term $0<C<1$ such that $\underset{M \in \mathbb{R}^2}{\max}(\mu(A \cap s_M(A)))=C$.

(Say differently : take a compact set of measure 1. Take a picture of it, do a half-turn rotation, and translate it such that the matching part has maximal measure).

I wonder how to find sets with the lowest possible constant. Is it studied somewhere?

Thanks in advance for your comments :)

Comment: It's probably the triangle. I say "the" because they are all affinely equivalent. There are some results concerning their lack of a center of symmetry, maybe not exactly what you stated.

Comment: well, maybe not, but if you have some references it would be nice, thanks!

Comment: There was a related problem about balanced cuttings... see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589723/balanced-cutting-of-a-convex-polygon/1589791#1589791

Comment: If the compactness hypothesis is too general, feel free to suggest a restricted case where more things are known ;)

Comment: I think a convex compact can be approximated from within by a convex symmetric compact within some ration of the volume...

Comment: It seems a rather rough approximation, I need to investigate if it is sharper than I think.

Comment: Yes, it will only give you a lower bound for $C$

Comment: I would first find $C$ for a triangle.

Comment: Notice that $A \cap s_M(A)$ is symmetric wr to $M$. So your problem is in fact equivalent to approximating a compact set with a symmetric compact set from within